# It is possible to integrate symfony2 with yii2 framework?

Tags: php, symfony, yii, yii2

I am working on a symfony2 project and i really feel a lot is lacking. Of course there are packages available to solve those gaps.

But i would like to know if anyone has ever used yii2 inside a symfony application and how did it work.

My try on it is as follows:

Add to my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "classmap": [ ... , "vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php" ]
},
"require": {
    ...,
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*"
}
```

Then edit the `app/autoloader.php` to instantiate a yii application:

```
new \yii\web\Application([
    'id' => '(',
    'basePath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'AppBundle\Controller',
    // other configs
]);
```

I can use `Yii::$app` inside symfony, but is there a better approach to integrating these 2 frameworks together? I am mainly interested in the REST api capabilities of the yii2 framework

Comment: Have you checked out the [*FOSRestBundle*](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) for Symfony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In future Yii would probably allow using its parts separately but today there is no better approach: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-yii-in-others

Comment: Thank you @Sam 
What difference there is in doing: `require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');` and `"classmap": [ ... , "vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php" ]`

Comment: The difference is in autoloading order. In case of classmap, Composer one is used first. In case of require, Yii's is used first. Yii autoloader, while PSR-4 compatible, uses additional tricks such as defining path aliases by the name of the extension.

Comment: Would there be issues if i use the Composer one over the require one?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. In fact, Yii entry point has composer autoload first.